# ROS2 Dashing service `get_entity_state` is missing

Tags: gazebo, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using **ROS2 Dashing**. There, I launched the following commands:

1. `gazebo --verbose world -s libgazebo_ros_factory.so`

I got the following answer:

```
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 9.14.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

[Msg] Waiting for master.
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 9.14.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

[Msg] Waiting for master.
[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
[Msg] Publicized address: 172.17.0.2
[INFO] [gazebo_ros_node]: ROS was initialized without arguments.
[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
[Msg] Publicized address: 172.17.0.2
[Wrn] [GuiIface.cc:119] QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
[Wrn] [Publisher.cc:185] Queue limit reached for topic /gazebo/default/user_camera/pose, deleting message. This warning is printed only once.
```

2. `ros2 service call /spawn_entity 'gazebo_msgs/SpawnEntity' '{name: "urdf_ball", xml: "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?><robot name=\"will_be_ignored\"><link name=\"link\"><visual><geometry><sphere radius=\"1.0\"/></geometry></visual><inertial><mass value=\"1\"/><inertia ixx=\"1\" ixy=\"0.0\" ixz=\"0.0\" iyy=\"1\" iyz=\"0.0\" izz=\"1\"/></inertial></link></robot>"}'`

I copied it from [gazebo_ros_pkgs](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/wiki/ROS-2-Migration:-Spawn-and-delete#spawn-urdf-robot).

I got the responce

```
response:
gazebo_msgs.srv.SpawnEntity_Response(success=True, status_message='SpawnEntity: Successfully spawned entity [urdf_ball]')
```

3. `ros2 service list`

And I received the following responce

```
/delete_entity
/gazebo/describe_parameters
/gazebo/get_parameter_types
/gazebo/get_parameters
/gazebo/list_parameters
/gazebo/set_parameters
/gazebo/set_parameters_atomically
/get_model_list
/hros_cognition_3f1e831f2728/describe_parameters
/hros_cognition_3f1e831f2728/get_parameter_types
/hros_cognition_3f1e831f2728/get_parameters
/hros_cognition_3f1e831f2728/list_parameters
/hros_cognition_3f1e831f2728/set_parameters
/hros_cognition_3f1e831f2728/set_parameters_atomically
/launch_ros/describe_parameters
/launch_ros/get_parameter_types
/launch_ros/get_parameters
/launch_ros/list_parameters
/launch_ros/set_parameters
/launch_ros/set_parameters_atomically
/robot_state_publisher/describe_parameters
/robot_state_publisher/get_parameter_types
/robot_state_publisher/get_parameters
/robot_state_publisher/list_parameters
/robot_state_publisher/set_parameters
/robot_state_publisher/set_parameters_atomically
/spawn_entity
```

4. Next I **want to** do **but can not** do the following

`ros2 service call / get_entity_state gazebo_msgs/GetEntityState '{name: urdf_ball, reference_frame: world}'`

My question is:
**Why the service `get_entity_state` is missing?**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/360161/ros2-dashing-service-%60get_entity_state%60-is-missing/) by [Lyubomyr](https://answers.ros.org/users/58058/lyubomyr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2020-08-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `get_entity_state` service is provided by the `libgazebo_ros_state.so` plugin. Did you load that?

[Here](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/c071749932a541a5b8aced23c3414724a8cd1949/gazebo_ros/worlds/gazebo_ros_state_demo.world#L41-L49)'s an example on how to load it from your SDF world.

There isn't a way to load that plugin from a launch file yet, see [this issue](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/issues/1157).

[Here](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/wiki/ROS-2-Migration:-Entity-states)'s more information on entity states on Gazebo + ROS 2.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.ros.org/users/4654/chapulina/) with karma: 366 on 2020-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lyubomyr](https://answers.ros.org/users/58058/lyubomyr/) on 2020-09-02**:
Thank you!